# For Loop with Second Parameter String put in between spaces in First Parameter String

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am very new to python and need to write a program that uses a phrase as the first parameter, with a second parameter being a string that is to be used as padding placed between each of the words in the phrase, replacing the existing white space(s) in the phrase.

There must be no padding after the last word in the phrase--this can be shown by using "..." (three dots) as the padding string. For an idea of what I need, look at the following examples:

> > > inputPhrase("Once upon a time a long time ago", "   ")
> > >       would result in the following output:
> > >       Once   upon   a   time   a   long   time   ago

where there is now padding of three spaces between each word.

And to show that there is no padding after the last word. Example below.

> > > inputPhrase("Once upon a time a long time ago", "...")
> > >       Once...upon...a...time...a...long...time...ago

Two checks also need to be made:

1. An appropriate error message must be produced if the padding string is not between 1 and 5 characters in length:

> > > inputPhrase("Once upon a time a long time ago", "")
> > >       Padding must be between 1 and 5 characters. You had 0 characters
> > >       inputPhrase("Once upon a time a long time ago", "      ")
> > >       Padding must be between 1 and 5 characters. You had 6 characters

2. If a null phrase is entered, produce an appropriate error message:

> > > inputPhrase("", "   ")
> > >       Null phrase. Enter at least one character, a word, or words separated by a space or spaces

Comment: SO doesn't code people's projects for them, you will have to show proof of effort before we can afford to put effort in helping to fix an *issue*

Answer (score 0):

Following code should do it. But note for future reference, pls show what you have tried too.

```
def inputPhrase(s, padding):
    if s==None:
        print("Null phrase. Enter at least one character, a word, or words separated by a space or spaces.")
        return

    if len(padding)>5 or len(padding)<1:
        print("You had", len(padding),"characters, Padding must be between 1 and 5 characters.")
        return

    print(s.replace(' ',padding))

inputPhrase("Once upon a time a long time ago", '...')
#Once...upon...a...time...a...long...time...ago

inputPhrase(None,'a')
#Null phrase. Enter at least one character, a word, or words separated by a space or spaces.

inputPhrase("Once upon a time a long time ago",'')
#You had 0 characters, Padding must be between 1 and 5 characters.
```